# Show incorrect current timestamp

Tags: postgresql-9.5

Column type is **timestamp with time zone**

current date is 2020-09-17 10:22:07.047107+00

To get current date I use:

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The result is

```
2020-09-17 07:22:07.047107+00
```

Why print not correct date? Must be **2020-09-17 10:22:07.047107+00**

plus 3 hours

Comment: I'll bet your time zone is 3 hours from GMT ;)

Comment: Yes, GMT+3. So how I can fix the  problem?

Comment: I'll also bet you declared the column `timestamp`, instead of `timestampz`:  https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp/